# JQuery hover over quadrant

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to create a JQuery page with a hover over effect. when it hovers over the top left quadrant of the page, a div must be filled with text, and different text for the other three quadrants over the page.

I am new to JQuery, but I do have a programming background of some sort so I do know how to navigate through the language. I am going to use the css properties to change the text in the div's as they will be different divs, displayed in the same spot (so I will alter their visibility/display) or should I rather go with JQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()` methods?

My main question, is how do I set up the page so that JQuery picks up when the mouse is in the top left quadrant, top right quadrant, bottom left quadrant or bottom right quadrant of the screen?

Thanks in advance, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind on `mousemove` event and compare cursor position with window width and height. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/DUJQ4

```
<div id="topleft" class="message">Top Left</div>
<div id="topright" class="message">Top Right</div>
<div id="bottomleft" class="message">Bottom Left</div>
<div id="bottomright" class="message">Bottom Right</div>

$(function(){
    var current; //will save current quadrant here
    $(document).mousemove(function(ev){
        var left = ev.pageX, top = ev.pageY, //cursor coordinats
            win = $(window),
            width = win.width(), height = win.height(), horizontal, vertical, id;

        horizontal = (left < width/2) ? "left": "right"; 
        vertical = (top < height/2) ? "top": "bottom";
        id = vertical + horizontal;
        if(id == current) { //not changed
            return;
        }
        current = id;
        $(".message").hide(); //hide all messages
        $("#" + id).show(); //show only one with corrent id.            
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a restriction about wich browser will run your website, I suggest that you use `css` instead `jquery`

[see this example](http://jsbin.com/orANoNE/1/edit)

**UPDATE**
BUT, if you want to do this with jquery you need to use the `$('.mainMenu').hover(function hoverIn(), function hoverOut())`. Then inside each function parameter you need to change the style properties to change the display value to `none`(hiden) or `block`(visible)

[See this example](http://jsbin.com/eriwAgu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I need the page to be clean with nothing on it and then when the user moves to the one quadrant all the page divs are filled with different information. how would I do this?

Comment: as I explain in my edited answer you need to you the `$().hover()` see the example.